# Bootstrap CSS not formatting correctly

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

The Bootstrap guide shows a horizontal form.
http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#tables
I couldn't get it to style it horizontally.
I created a JSFiddle -- it also doesn't work.
Here's the code from the above page

```
 <form class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Email</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <input type="text" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Password</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <input type="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
          <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
          </label>
          <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign in</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

I am trying to use Bootstrap to format my form to have the label on the left, textbox on the right.
Seems simple, right?

http://jsfiddle.net/nwkZz/

This is what I want:

> MyLabel MyTextbox

and not:

> MyLabel
>   MyTextbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Bootstrap 2.1.0 you are including the wrong css, you must include the `Bootstrap 2.1.0` css.

Like: //cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/as9Kv/

Comment: Perfect!  It took me a while to figure out why you were talking about Bootstrap v2.  It was the result of a google search and I didn't realize I was looking at the markup for an older version.